# Access nested dictionaries' data

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using dicts to storage some data in this format:

```
users_data = {'user_1':{'Name':'Carlos','Age':25,'address':'adress','height':170},
             'user_2':{'Name':'Pedro','Age':22,'address':'adress','height':175},
             'user_3':{'Name':'Ana','Age':51,'address':'adress','height':163}}
```

So I can do this:

```
users_data['user_1']['Age']
```

25

```
`users_data`['user_1']['height']
```

170

But this starts becoming annoying if I need to use that data constantly in other functions, for example if I have:

```
def foo(age,address,height):
     do something
```

I'll need to call the function like:

```
foo(users_data`['user_1']['age'] ,users_data`['user_1']['address'],users_data`['user_1']['height'] )
```

There is a shorter  way to do this? something like:

```
users_data['user_1'][['age','address','height']]
```

Comment: Why not just define `u1=users_data['user_1']` and then call `foo(u1['age'], u1['address'], u1['height'])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
foo(*(users_data['user_1'][k] for k in ('Age', 'address', 'height')))
```

For more details refer to [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: It's OK as is (+1), but I'd rather write it as a helper function to communicate more clearly the meaning of the (relatively) obscure argument of `foo`, `foo(*access(users_data['user_1'], 'Age', 'address', 'height'))` — of course the name `access` is not the best possible one, but this is just a comment.

Comment: Of course you can! This was just an example to show how you can approach this problem. If you want to write a function which access these properties that's your call to make :).

Answer (score 1):

Change your Function like this

```
In [28]: def foo((a,b,c)):
    print a,b,c
```

And Do some thing like this with your dict.

```
In [29]: from operator import itemgetter
In [30]: foo(itemgetter('Age', 'address', 'height')(users_data['user_1']))
```

`itemgetter` will return a tuple if more than one argument is passed. For more reference about [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: @AKS That's why i suggested a slight modification in function. You can see my suggestion it;s meets his need.

Comment: Is it a better practice to define functions that way?